# Breeze.js 1.4.2 EFContextProvider no longer has a Metadata() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze

Is Breeze.js 1.4.2 from NuGet broken? EFContextProvider no longer has a Metadata() method. Has this been changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the release notes for v 1.4.2, ([release notes here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download)) we broke up the Breeze.WebApi assembly so that we could support a variety of different persistence frameworks.

In Breeze 1.4.2, the EFContextProvider class in the Breeze.WebApi.EF assembly now inherits from the ContextProvider class in the Breeze.WebApi assembly.  So you still have a Metadata method on the EFContextProvider but it is now being supplied by the ContextProvider base class.

The only breaking change in this release is that you will now need to reference 2 assemblies, Breeze.WebApi and Breeze.WebApi.EF instead of just one, and you will need to add a "using Breeze.WebApi.EF" clause to any classes that used to have just a ref to "using Breeze.WebApi".